# ASP.NET MVC - PartialView not refreshing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a user control: VendorDDL.ascx, with the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<MeetingCalendar.Models.Vendor>>" %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            VendorId
        </th>
        <th>
            VendorName
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.VendorId) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.VendorName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

---

My view: Create.aspx, has the following code snippet:

```
<p>
            <label for="VendorNameSearch">Vendor Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="VendorNameSearch" id="VendorNameSearch" style="width:100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="search" />
        </p>

<% Html.RenderPartial("VendorDDL", MeetingCalendar.Controllers.HomeController.VendorsToSelect); %>
```

---

And everything works fine when I load up the Create view.  The VendorDDL control is populated with the default values that are found in the VendorsToSelect.  My controller has a `List<Vendor> VendorsToSelect`, which is getting updated properly.

Here is the problem: when the user clicks the SEARCH button, this fires off code in the Controller: `return PartialView("VendorDDL", VendorsToSelect);`  I can see that VendorsToSelect is getting populated correctly based upon the user search.

I can step through the code, line-by-line, and see that immediately after `return PartialView("VendorDDL", VendorsToSelect);`, the debugger goes directly to the VendorDDL.ascx, and I can see that the Model is properly populated with the new VendorsToSelect, and the item.VendorId and item.VendorName are showing the correct values.  But when debugging is done, and the Create view is shown, the VendorDDL control is not showing the new data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the output of your controller is discarded because the view (Create) has the same Html.RenderPartial("VendorDDL", MeetingCalendar.Controllers.HomeController.VendorsToSelect) as during initial load.

If I understand your problem correctly (and admittedly, without looking at the controller I may not) - you need to pass the model dynamically. The simplest (but not the most efficient) way would be to have jquery call $.load("/Home/VendorDDL") that would populate with the whole model; and then on submit hijax the form and pass form data to the same controller action.